# Wrong argument? Matrix multiplication

Tags: linear-algebra, abstract-algebra

Let $f:K \rightarrow K$ be a linear transformation defined as $f(x) = a\cdot x$ where $a\in K$ and $K$ is a field extension of $F$. Let $A$ be the matrix that represents the transformation hence we obtain (where $I$ is the identity matrix):

$Ak = a\cdot k = a\cdot Ik$ for all $k\in K$ and thus we conclude $A = a\cdot I$.

Is this true? I think it works but I have tried this argument with an example and the equality I end up with was strange.

Comment: Well, what is $I$ in $K^{1\times 1}$?

Comment: If you're thinking of $A$ as a linear operator on $K$ as a vector space over $F$, then note that $a\not\in F$ (in the general case), so $A$ isn't a multiple of the identity mapping.

Comment: I dont think I understand your notation $K^{1\times 1}$. But I is the identity matrix.

Comment: Okay. But which step is wrong?

Comment: What does $a\cdot I$ mean if $a$ is not an element of the scalar field $F$?

Comment: Suppose it means that $a$ is on the diagonal.

Comment: It cannot be; only elements of $F$ are allowed as entries in the representing matrix.

Comment: The original exercise is to show that the characteristic polynomial of $A$ has $a$ as root. That is: det($xI-A$)=0 when $x=a$. So I don't know what else to expect of the expression $a\cdot I$?

Comment: As a polynomial over $K$, it has the root $a$; as a polynomial over $F$, it therefore has non-linear factors.

Comment: Okay. But again what is wrong with my argumentation? I admit it's a strange result, but I can't see which step I'm doing wrong - where is my argumentation wrong? From the exercise it is clear that $a\cdot I$ makes sense.

Comment: What's wrong is that $a\cdot I$ is not a matrix representation of a linear operator on $K$ over $F$. See @Jim's answer.

Answer (score 2):

The key here is that $A$ is most likely meant to represent a linear transformation of $K$ as a vector space **over $F$**.  The matrix representing a linear transformation over $F$ should have entries that lie in $F$, it cannot have entries that lie in $K \setminus F$.

Maybe an example would help.  Let $K = \mathbb C$, which is an extension of $F = \mathbb R$ and let $a = i$ (the square root of $-1$).  As the base field is $\mathbb R$ the entries of our matrix must be real numbers, so $i$ cannot be in our matrix.  To get the matrix observe that $\mathbb C$ has basis $1, i$ over $\mathbb R$.  Mult by $i$ sends $1 \mapsto i$ and $i \mapsto -1$ so we get
$$A = \begin{bmatrix} 0 & -1 \\ 1 & 0 \end{bmatrix}$$
The characteristic of $A$ is $x^2 + 1$ and $i$ is indeed a root.

On the other hand, if we think of $\mathbb C$ as a vector space over itself then the entries of our matrix are allowed to lie in $\mathbb C$.  To get the matrix observe that $\mathbb C$ has basis $1$ and mult by $i$ sends $1 \mapsto i\cdot 1$ so
$$A = \begin{bmatrix} i \end{bmatrix}$$
The characteristic is $x - i$ and $i$ is a root, but in this case the result is trivial so it's much more likely that you are supposed to consider the map as linear over $F$ and not linear over $K$.